# PowerShell - Install-WindowsFeature (and family) missing on Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

We have some Powershell scripts used to set up various dev/test/prod environments and one of them installs and configures IIS.  Unfortunately these scripts don't appear to be working under Windows 10 at this time because the Install-WindowsFeature cmdlet is missing.

Where these removed intentionally, or is there some hoop I need to jump through to install them that wasn't previously necessary?

Comment: is it the home version?

Comment: Enterprise actually.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

While Ryan's answer is correct, I would recommend to stay away from the `Install-WindowsFeature` cmdlets if you want to run your scripts on workstations as well. You will always be dependent on RSAT even though you don't need it otherwise.

Just use [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852172.aspx) which works on servers and workstations. You would need to change your scripts, the feature names are different too.

I wrote a bit about: [Different ways for installing Windows features on the command line](https://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/WindowsFeatureViaCmd.html)

Comment: I'm accepting this one as it seems more flexible and politely points out that I'm doing it wrong.  :)  Now, off to find out if the xml template I've been feeding into Install-WindowsFeature will work with Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature as well.

Comment: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` has a bit of weird behavior though. It doesn't allow you to suppress the confirm prompt. It makes it unfit for use in an automated provision-er like chef. I don't have a better answer, I was just surprised that it was written in a way that doesn't respect Powershell's builtin confirm preference.

Comment: @JasonMorgan - Do you have an example for such a case?

Answer (score 2):

It's not out yet. As always, Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT - also includes the `*-WindowsFeature` cmdlets) have always been very sensitive to OS version. I.e., you'd use Windows 7 RSAT on Windows 7 to manage Server 2008 R2, Windows 8.1 RSAT on Win 8.1 to manage Server 2012 R2, etc. Using RSAT across OS versions *may* work, but it may also crash unexpectedly. The `*-WindowsFeature` cmdlets are technically part of the `ServerManager` module, and since Server 2016 isn't out yet, you might not see these cmdlets for a while.

Might be able to get this to work: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Or, if not, just find a downlevel Windows workstation to do your remote administration from for now.

Comment: Only a side note to your answer, RSAT for Windows 10 is expected this month and will arrive alongside Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 3

Comment: For the record, this is all being done locally.  But a dependency is a dependency.

Comment: @Mr.Smythe Of course, outside the scoop of your question, if you manage your servers from those machine, you might still need RSAT in the end

Comment: fyi; https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520 :)  published today (and winserv 2016 technical preview 3 too!) /cc @Mr.Smythe

Answer (score 0):

You will also see this error on Server 2012/16/19 if you execute the command form the x86 version of PowerShell
[The Term ‘Uninstall-WindowsFeature’ is not Recognized](https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001628)